# Regex: exclude lines beginning with whitespace

Tags: regex

I want to match any line starting with some arbitrary number of asterisks, followed by a whitespace and some text. For example:

```
** some text
```

This is what I'm using:

```
/(\A\**)\ (.*)/
```

That works fine, except for the case where the line begins with a whitespace. As you can see in [this example at rubular](http://rubular.com/r/TK3JOIos8W), the whitespace is the first match group and the asterisks and text are the second. All my attempts to fix it have ended up matching other, non-asterisk characters. What's the proper way to do this?

Edit: I wasn't clear: I want the match fail if the line starts with whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your targeted line needs to start with `*` with optional spaces at the beginning, then you should use `+`(means one or more) instead of `*`(means zero or more) with optional spaces `[ ]*`

```
^[ ]*[*]+ (.*)
```

Comment: Ah, yes: + instead of *. Thanks!